# minimal document size in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

Wat is the minimal document size in MongoDb.

If I insert the following Json `{"_id",1234}` or `{"_id":NumberLong(1),"g":"1383,5,2000,1"}` or `{"_id":ObjectId("5652e26c1a8014b040aacc54"),"v" : "3,123"}`.

All three documents takes up 48 bytes. Is 48 bytes the minimum size of the document?

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB supports dynamic schema i.e documents within same collection might have different schema.

So there is no fixed minimal size of document in MongoDB.
To determine size of document in MongoDB execute the following code snippet

> db.test.stats()

Following is response of stats() method

```
{
    "ns" : "pcat.test",
    "count" : 2,
    "size" : 736,
    "avgObjSize" : 368,
    "numExtents" : 1,
    "storageSize" : 8192,
    "lastExtentSize" : 8192.0000000000000000,
    "paddingFactor" : 1.0000000000000000,
    "paddingFactorNote" : "paddingFactor is unused and unmaintained in 3.0. It remains hard coded to 1.0 for compatibility only.",
    "userFlags" : 1,
    "capped" : false,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "indexDetails" : {},
    "totalIndexSize" : 16352,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 8176,
        "accounts.platform_id_1_accounts.id_1" : 8176
    },
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

From above mentioned output key **avgObjSize** consists of avg document size (in bytes) across collection.

Alternative you can determine size of individual document in collection using following code snippet

```
Object.bsonsize(db.collection.find({ "_id" :1}))
```

But there is a restriction to maximum size of document in MongoDB.

> The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes. The maximum document
>   size helps ensure that a single document cannot use excessive amount
>   of RAM or, during transmission, excessive amount of bandwidth.

Comment: But if I look at the avgObjSize in db.collection.stats() with the json `{"_id",1234}` that is the same as I look at the avgObjSize in db.collection2.stats() with the json `{"_id":NumberLong(1),"g":"1383,5,2000,1"}`.

Both are 48 bytes.

Comment: how to use Object.bsonsize in nodejs, using mongoose driver, what is the import statement?